# passing parameters hash to jquery css()

Tags: jquery, css, hash

Can anyone show me how to pass this hash of css property/value pairs to the jquery css function via a javascript function?

```
var $myFunction = function(el, c){

  $(el).css(c);
  //$(el).css({c});

};

$myFunction("#myDiv", '{top:50px}');
//$myFunction("#myDiv", 'top:50px');
```

EDIT: I'VE UPDATED THIS FIDDLE TO SHOW WORKING SOLUTION AS PER DAN PHILIP'S ANSWER...

[Here's the **UPDATED** fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doublecream/we33kmby/9/)

For the life of me I can't see where I'm going to wrong - have tried so many different permutations of the same.

Many thanks in advance to anyone that can take a look...

Cheers, Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS method takes params in the following format

```
$(elem).css({ 
   "border" : "1px solid blue", 
   "display" : "block",     
   "background" : "#F00" 
});
```

So your code should be modified to

```
$myFunction("#myDiv", {
   "top" : "50px"
 });
```

Comment: many thanks! I've updated the fiddle in the question to reflect your solution. Cheers, S

Comment: Happy to help.!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an object (of property-value pairs to set) to the [`.css(properties)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) method so accept in your function too.

```
$myFunction("#myDiv", {
  top: "50px",
  background: "red"
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/we33kmby/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Just do

> $(el).css(JSON.parse(c));

to solve your problem.

> Note: You need to also use quotes while creating a property:value pair, ie you have to construct your parameter as '{top:"50px"}'

**.css()** function accepts PlainObject that accepts property-value pairs. When you call $myfunction, it passes the second parameter as a string.JSON.parse() converts it into a valid object.

Cheers